# Is it possible to change y position of a view for smaller screen size?

Tags: swift, frame

I am working on a UICollectionview and setting my collectionView as below,

```
var isListView = false
var collectionView: UICollectionView?
func collectionViewSetUp() {
    collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,collectionViewLayout: gridLayout)
    collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.delegate = self
    collectionView?.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    collectionView?.allowsSelection = true
    collectionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    collectionView?.register(collectionViewListLayoutCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewListLayoutCell")

collectionView?.register(collectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell")
```

And i have two layouts as,

```
lazy var listLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    //Assign a new cell for list view
    let listLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    listLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    listLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 12, bottom: 4, right: 12)
    listLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/1.12, height: 98)
    listLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    listLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    folderCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,collectionViewLayout: listLayout)
    view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    isListView = true
   return listLayout
}()
```

and for Grid-

```
lazy var gridLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let gridLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
     gridLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
     gridLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 15, right: 10)
    gridLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/3.5, height: view.frame.size.width/2.3)
    gridLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
    gridLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 9
    folderCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,collectionViewLayout: gridLayout)
    view.addSubview(folderCollectionView!)
    isListView = false
    return gridLayout
}()
```

Here Setting viewDidLayoutSubViews,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = appBackgroundColor
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.delegate = self
    
    collectionView?.frame = CGRect(x: 11, y: 162, width: self.view.frame.width-20, height: self.view.frame.height-165)
}
```

On the UIButton action i am just switching my layouts and refreshing my collectionView.

Now as I have set x and y position there, the space above UICollectionview is looking too much for older devices like iphone-8 and older. But in devices like iphone x and newer it is looking fine.
So how can i adjust it for older devices, not having top notch like newer?
Is it possible to do that?
Here i am not setting NSLayoutConstraints for collectionView.
Problem that i am facing with setting constraints to my collectioView is that my collectionView is not changing the layout from grid to list.

Comment: The easiest way - and what Apple steers you towards - is to use constraints, not frames. (And it's really best to use one or the other, they don't play nicely.) But if you use frames? First, don't tag this question as [autolayout]. That *is* constraints. Second, please provide more code - as frames are *much* more dependent on the view controller life cycle.

Comment: Hey dfd i know that it is easy to use constraints but here i am using frame because i have to give a UIButton which will change the layout of collectionView from grid to list & vice-versa. So when i am setting the constraints of collectionView, the layout is not changing but when I am using frame, change layout button is working perfectly. So thats why i am using frame here.

Comment: If I may? My comments stand. This *is not* properly tagged. (I could remove the [autolayout] tag but don't think it's proper for me.) And, what little code you posted makes it hard to help you. Of course, you can change the Y position of a frame! It may not work well with with any constraints you also have, but that's (hopefully) not your issue. But if you could post something for me to actually be able to duplicate what you are facing, I'd be happy to try to help. For now, I cannot.

Comment: Hey dfd, I have updated my question with more code and also removed autolayout tag from there. So now is it understandable? If yes please let me know?

Comment: Upvoted, but I'm pretty sure I cannot help. That said, a few thoughts? Have you tried removing the `lazy` declarations? Second, you *can* safely remove most of your `viewDidLayoutSubview` code into `viewDidLoad` - pretty much everything besides declaring `collectionView?.frame`. It's redundant. Last thought... look into what `self.view.frame` is inside the override your have. There's no guarantee that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will only be called once. (Many times it isn't.) Maybe that might help. Anyways, thanks for posting more code.

Comment: Thanks dfd, sure I will try removing lazy.

Comment: when I am removing lazy, i am getting this error: Instance member 'view' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?